# Read complex numbers from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am having problem reading complex number from a csv file. 
The format of the file is the following:

```
( -353.10438 +j1.72317617 ),( -23.16000 +j0.72512251 )
```

I tried importing the data using numpy.genfromtxt:

```
data=genfromtxt(fname, dtype=complex, skip_header=10, skip_footer=212, delimiter=',')
```

But every time I have a complex entry it returns me `nan+0.j`. 
I also tried removing the brackets before and after the number, and replacing the `j` with `1j*` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: genfromtxt is in numpy.

Comment: Presumably you mean that you tried *importing* the data with genfromtxt?

Comment: @BillBell yes, you're right. fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I moved each 'j' to the position immediately behind the imaginary part of the complex number and squeezed out all the blanks to get a sample file like this.

```
(-353.10438+1.72317617j),(-23.16000+0.72512251j)
(-353.10438+1.72317617j),(-23.16000+0.72512251j)
(-353.10438+1.72317617j),(-23.16000+0.72512251j)
(-353.10438+1.72317617j),(-23.16000+0.72512251j)
```

Then I ran code similar to yours with a result similar to what follows.

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('fname.txt', dtype=complex, delimiter=',')
array([[-353.10438+1.72317617j,  -23.16000+0.72512251j],
       [-353.10438+1.72317617j,  -23.16000+0.72512251j],
       [-353.10438+1.72317617j,  -23.16000+0.72512251j],
       [-353.10438+1.72317617j,  -23.16000+0.72512251j]])
```

I don't know exactly what you might have to do to get similar results, if indeed this approach will work for you at all.

Best of luck!

Comment: I managed by doing how you said and eliminating the space before the +. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
np.complex(str(a).replace('j', '') + 'j'
```

to first cast to a string, then shift the 'j' and cast back to a complex number.

Comment: I used replace from the data directly. `data=fname.read()` and than `data=data.replace()`
But I guess it's exactly the same as you said

Comment: Yeah, the replace you can use whenever.. just before the actual parse to a complex number, since this must always be in the form "a+bj" in order to cast correctly.